# Call to a member function children() on a non-object but i need to continue execution

Tags: php, dom

that i need is;
Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object
i know the cause of this but i need to continue executing and i can't
My problem is that i want to take eight images from my page and im doing this;

```
do {
        if(is_Object($html2->find("#ficha_fotos",0)->children($j)) === true){
            if($html2->find("#ficha_fotos",0)->children($j)->children(0)->src){
                $imggran = $html2->find("#ficha_fotos",0)->children($j)->children(0)->src."<br />";
                $imggran = explode(".", $imggran);
                $imggran[2] = $imggran[2]."G";
                $salidaimg = implode('.',$imggran);
                echo $salidaimg;
            }
            $j++;
        }else {
            $j++;
        }
    } while($j < 50);
```

but in some pages i got less than eight so i need to avoid this error and continue executing.
thanks and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: try `@is_Object(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
do {
    $isObject = false;
    if ( is_Object($html2->find("#ficha_fotos",0)) === true && is_Object($html2->find("#ficha_fotos",0)->children($j)) === true ) {
        $isObject = true;
    }
    if($isObject){
```

Comment: Still have the same problem sorry.

Comment: Fix it! Srry i mistake in one place Thank you so much u are very helpful for me!